# perl regexp with sas - exact match one or the other

Tags: regex, perl, sas

I need to extract numbers written in words or in figures in  a text.

I have a table that looks like that,

```
... 1 child ...
... three children ... 
...four children ...    
...2 children...
...five children
```

I want capture a number written in words or in numeric figures. There is one number per line. So the desired output would be:

```
1
three
four
2
five
```

My regex looks like that:

```
prxparse("/one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|child|\d\d?/")
```

Any help ?

Comment: What do you mean by "i would like to match exactly one or two or 2 or four." ? You only want to match the strings "one", "two", "2" and "four" ?

Comment: I want capture a number written in words or in figures. There is one number per line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Description

This regex will match the numbers in the string providing the numbers are surrounded by whitespace or the symbols.

`(?<=\s|^)(?:[0-9]+|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten)(?=\s|$)`

[image]

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/6ua7fTb8IS

To include the spelled out word version of numbers outside of one - ten, you'll need to include those. This regex will capture the numbers from zero to one hundred [baring any typos]

`(?<=\s|^)(?:[0-9]+|(?:(?:twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety)\s)?(?:one(?:[\s-]hundred)?|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)|ten|eleven|twelve|(?:thir|four|fif|six|seven|eight|nine)teen|twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety|zero)(?=\s|$)`

[image]

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/EIa18nx731

## Perl Example

```
 $string = <<END;
 ... 1 child ...
 ... three children ... 
 ... four children ...    
 ... 2 children...
 ... five children
END
@matches = $string =~ m/(?<=\s|^)[0-9]+|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten(?=\s|$)/gi;
    print join("\n", @matches);
```

Yields

```
1
three
four
2
five
```

Comment: What program are you using to produce those graphics!!? That is amazing.

Comment: @ Rob Penridge. Thanks :)  I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Comment: Also, I believe `ninety` is spelt with an `e`.  You appear to be missing it. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ninety

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I am dealing with a lot of other chalenges  actually. Many thanks for the tips. But the regexp doesn't seem to be working in SAS or it might be possible that i don't know how to implement it as well. Do you have any tutorial of peal regexp at hand? Thanks.

Comment: I think you're looking for perl, if so have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html, http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html, or http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/perl_regexp/regexp-tip-sheet.pdf I also updated the expressions in the answer to be more cross platform compliant.